# How do I use a MethodExpression with parameters for a custom JSF component?

Tags: jsf, el, custom-component

I'm attempting to write a custom JSF tree component which supports adding a listener as an attribute:

```
<foo:tree value="#{barController.treeNodes}"
                  type="sidenav"
                  onNodeSelect="#{barController.onTreeClick}">
</foo:tree>
```

The listener would take in an event parameter, like so:

```
public void onTreeClick(TreeSelectEvent event) {}
```

The component class has getters/setters for the Method expression as follows:

```
/**
 * @return the onNodeSelect
 */
public MethodExpression getOnNodeSelect() {
    return (MethodExpression ) getStateHelper().eval(PropertyKeys.onNodeSelect);
}

/**
 * @param onNodeSelect the onNodeSelect to set
 */
public void setOnNodeSelect(MethodExpression onNodeSelect) {
    getStateHelper().put(PropertyKeys.onNodeSelect, onNodeSelect);
}
```

However, when I call component.getOnNodeSelect() I get the following error:

```
Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /sandbox.xhtml @22,73 onNodeSelect="#   {barController.onTreeClick}": The class 'com.bar.barController$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy' does not have   the property 'onTreeClick'.
 at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:111)
 at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
 at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
```

It seems that JSF is treating my MethodExpression as a ValueExpression instead, and trying to call some getter to find the property. Is there any way I can force it to use a MethodExpression?

I've even tried updating the tag-lib to add a method signature:

```
<attribute>
        <name>onNodeSelect</name>
        <description>The listener to be called when a node has been   selected</description>
        <method-signature>void  process(com.bar.tag.foundation.TreeSelectEvent)</method-signature>
        <type>javax.el.MethodExpression</type>
</attribute>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: BalusC - I don't know how you do it. I searched all day without finding any leads! The answer from that post seems to work. I wish there were a few more examples of writing Components and Client Behaviors. But until then, I'll read the spec. You're the master of JSF - is the solution proposed in that thread the proper way of adding MethodExpression attributes with parameters?

Comment: Try searching on the problem symptom, not on the requirement. Stack Overflow is basically one and all problems ;) I just searched using ["javax.el.MethodExpression javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javax.el.MethodExpression+javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException). Note that period-separated words like FQN class names are considered single search words. You get different results if you search on e.g. "MethodExpression PropertyNotFoundException". As to custom component examples, peek around in source code of JSF libraries such as PrimeFaces and OmniFaces.